# Sencha Extjs - Overriding methods properly?

Tags: javascript, class, extjs, overriding

I have a simple overriding class. That looks like this:

```
Ext.define('Ext.overrides.form.Panel',{
override: 'Ext.form.Panel',
constructor: function() {
    this.callParent(arguments);
},
listeners: {
    afterrender:  {
        fn:function (component, eOpts) {
            var fields = component.getForm().getFields();
            var field =  fields.getAt(0);
            if(typeof field !== 'undefined' && field.isFocusable()) {
                //need to wait before you can focus a field.
                Ext.defer(function() {
                    field.focus(true,200);
                },1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

});

As you can see, I am attempting to override the afterRender event so that the first field in the form will have focus once the form has been rendered.
This works, except for some forms in my application that are implementing some code in the afterrender events for themselves.  It appears that they are overriding this method I have defined above.

I can copy this piece of code in to those forms, but wouldn't it be better if I could call the code above using something like this.callParent(arguments); in those forms? 
I've actually tried that, but the problem is that my after render code for those forms is in view controller scope. So the 'this' reference will have the wrong scope of Ext.Base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Ext.define('Ext.overrides.form.Panel',{
  override: 'Ext.form.Panel',
  constructor: function() {
    this.callParent(arguments);

    this.on({
      afterrender: function (component, eOpts) {
            var fields = component.getForm().getFields();
            var field =  fields.getAt(0);
            if(typeof field !== 'undefined' && field.isFocusable()) {
                //need to wait before you can focus a field.
                Ext.defer(function() {
                    field.focus(true,200);
                },1);
            }
        }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. This answer works.  But why does adding the listener in this way work as opposed to making it part of the initial configs of class?

Comment: I'm thinking it's because on() is shorthand for addlistener, which means we can add multiple listeners to the same event?

Comment: If you use `listeners` like in your question some of your forms simply override it.